# Разбить список на подсписки не равной длинны

Tags: python

Есть список, например:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

необходимо получить список из списков:
с переменной длинной, а именно (в первом-1 элемент, во втором -2 элемента, в 3- три элемента и тд...). т.е.:

```
aa = [[0], [1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8,9], [10]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

aa = []
i = 0
n = 1
while i < len(a):
    aa.append(a[i:i+n])
    i = i+n
    n += 1

print(aa)
```